# How safe Port Forwarding and DDNS?

Tags: port-forwarding, ddns

My router password is a default password. And as per my Internet Service Provider, it’s recommended not to change router password.

In such case, if I setup Port Forwarding and DDNS, is it safe?

Regards

InTech

Comment: Your ISP(or to be correct - their representatives ) is unprofessional. Default password is the best food for Mirai botnet

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen to your ISP - change the password immediately to mitigate the risk! There are many tools available that will scan the internet for default router configs.

With that being said, port forwarding and DDNS does not bring much additional risk - unless you plan to publish a website that will be index by the search engines. In that case I would not do it.

But I would not leave a default password on my router under ANY circumstance either - EVER!

Comment: Earlier I ignored my ISP instruction and changed my router password. And because of this my internet service interrupted and as per ISP, at the time of password changing, new password couldn’t be synced successfully throughout the connection. And they changed password to default from their side.